# Which of the following statements is/are true regarding Chi square,T-distribution,F-distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3$ be i.i.d $N(0,1)$ random variables. Then which of the following statements is/are TRUE?

$(A) \ \ \dfrac{\sqrt2X_1}{\sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2}}\sim t_2$

$(B) \ \ \dfrac{\sqrt2X_1}{|X_2+X_3|}\sim t_1$

$(C) \ \ \dfrac{(X_1-X_2)^2}{(X_1+X_2)^2} \sim F_{1,1}$

$(D) \ \ \sum_{i=1}^{3}X_i^2 \sim \chi_{2}^2 $

$(A)$ is True because $X_1\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y=X_1^2\sim \chi_1^2$ and we know $\dfrac{\sqrt{1}X_1}{\sqrt{Y}}\sim t_{1}$

$X_1^2+X_2^2\sim\chi_2^2$

so it does follows $t_2$

$(C) $ is TRUE because $(X_1-X_2)$ and $(X_1+X_2)\sim N(0,2)$ and squaring and dividing by $\sqrt{2}$ gives standard normal. So ratio of two chi-square variates divided by their degrees of freedom gives F distribution with digrees of freedom $m$ and $n$ both being $1$ here.

$(D)$ is not TRUE.It should be $\chi_3^2$

$(B)$ I am not sure how to proceed in B's denominator. I know $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$ but how can I utilize it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous version of my answer was incorrect.

The reason why (B) is $t$-distributed is because $(X_2 + X_3)/\sqrt{2}$ is a standard normal variable; call this variable $Y$.  Thus $$\frac{|X_2 + X_3|}{\sqrt{2}} = \sqrt{Y^2}$$ is the square root of a chi-squared random variable with one degree of freedom; consequently (B) is $t$-distributed with one degree of freedom.

Comment: So doesnt follows $t_1$ right?

Comment: @Daman How could it?  If the numerator is standard normal but the denominator is not the square root of a chi-squared variable, then it cannot be $t$-distributed.

Comment: I agree,but the question I am solving came last year and options are A,B,C correct. [Here](https://prnt.sc/wnvm3f) and answer [key](https://prnt.sc/wnvn4p). So I am confused. This exam is from a very reputed institute its hard to believe if there is any mistake here.

Comment: @Daman Oh wait.  I made a mistake.  Let me modify my answer.

Comment: Makes sense how me and many more couldn't it do in first go. :)

Comment: Thanks, i understood now it was a tricky question.